# When do you use partials in compass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, compass-sass

I understand that partials in compass do not create a separate .css file. But I don't understand when/why would I ever want to use this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly just for organization and separation of logical pieces of CSS. For example, I keep a `_reset.scss` that I can paste into any project, then have things like `_layout.sass`, `_homepage.sass`, etc. They all get shoved into a single compiled CSS file (so I don't have to deal with multiple HTTP requests), but I can get to the styles for any given piece of a project quickly and easily.

Comment: But couldn't I just create `layout.sass`, `reset.scss` etc and get the same results using `include XX`? I still don't get it.

Comment: When you do that, you're effectively using those files as partials. :)

Comment: ok, so i guess it's just a personal preference whether you do it one way or the other?

Comment: Actually, I think I get it now. partials are used just for organizing sass files. While the actual .css files are what's included in your markup.